# HTML touchscreen increase text's "hit area" size?

Tags: html, css, touchscreen

I have to modify an HTML UI for a touchscreen system. A modification I have to do is to add a click handler to a certain text label inside a div tag. The text is fairly small.

So it will be hard to accurately hit it with the touchscreen. How can I increase the "hit area" of the text without increasing its size?

Comment: monitor the click events in a parent tag and do a hit test in javascipt.

Comment: I don't think you can increase the 'hit area' of a tag without increasing its size. Ask product management to consider redesigning the page for touch-screen users.

Answer (score 0):

You can add *padding* to increase hit area of any link. Here is an example you can check-

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="#" style="font-size: 12pt; color: blue; padding: 20px 60px">This is a link</a>
  </body?
</html>
```